# loop through 2 array of objects at a time using map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

I have a basic react question which i have digged enough but no conclusive result yet. hope someone can enlighten me here.

I have an array of objects as shown below

```
let response = [
  { "id": 1, "title": "Title 1" },
  { "id": 2, "title": "Title 2" },
  { "id": 3, "title": "Title 3" },
  { "id": 4, "title": "Title 3" }
]
```

I have a function component which takes in this response and loop through the array of objects and displays the data as shown below

```
{ response.map((data, index) => {
      return <div>{data.title}</div>
  })
}
```

This is pretty simple where i display each title one below the other in next line. However, i want to display data in a different way.

I need to show `Title 1` and `Title 2` in same line beside each other (Title 1 on left side  and Title 2 on right side) and `Title3` and `Title 4` in next line and so on.

How do i achieve that ? because the current map function allows to pass only one title each time

Comment: You can use css flexbox to display it the same line.

Comment: Maybe i didnt convey my question clearer. The map function passes only 1 object at a time to render. But i want 2 objects to be passed at a time. so i can render Title 1 and Title 2 beside each other

Comment: You need like this right? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-17-forked-owp92e

Comment: @ManirajMurugan- exactly wat i wanted. but is there a way to control the width. Suppose i want to show Title 1 with 100px width and Title 2 with 800px width. Can i dynamically achieve that for each title

Comment: Add `style={{'flex-basis': index % 2 ? '800px' : '100px'}}`

Comment: @Phil- i just tried adding the style to above codesandbox link. All titles display in new line when i do that.

Comment: @ArenTrot, The sandbox output area is smaller width so you need to drag the width and see it in bigger resolution. As you said `100px` and `800px` , it will be visible as per your expectation in larger screens.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan got you. can you post this as an answer. might be helpful for someone in future

Comment: Posted it as answer. For specifying certain width please give it in `%` , so that it will be responsive across the screens. Like this `style={{ "flex-basis": index % 2 ? "80%" : "20%" }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the two data in a row, you can use [css flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox),

**JSX:**

```
<div className="container">
  {response.map((data, index) => {
    return <div className="item">{data.title}</div>;
  })}
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > .item {
  flex: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit react-17 (forked)]

To split up the items with certain width then include `flex-basis` and assign value in `%` so that it will be responsive across the screens.

Add css like this,

`<div className="item" style={{ "flex-basis": index % 2 ? "80%" : "20%" }}>{data.title}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with a little trick of CSS. simply add the    `style={{ width: "calc(100% / 2)"}}`
to your div style

```
  {response.map((data, index) => {
    return (
      <span
        style={{
          width: "calc(100% / 2)"
        }}
      >
        {data.title}
      </span>
    );
  })}
```

Hope it will work for you.You can also check this link
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-17-forked-f17gig?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I saw in your comment you were asking how to control the grid sizes. Change the sandbox from @Maniraj container css to.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [first] 100px [line2] 80px;
}
```

You can use grid to make it two columns add control the size like above.